# How to reverse the order of just one column in excel/google sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Date   Home    Away
4/12   NY      TEX
4/12   TOR     ARI
4/12   LA      CIN
4/13   PHI     MIN
4/13   UTA     DEN
4/13   NAS     WYO
```

When I sort by Date either A to Z or Z to A, the Home and Away teams stay in the same order.  How can I make the Home and Away columns reverse their current order?  Meaning the result would look like this:

```
Date   Home    Away
4/12   LA      CIN
4/12   TOR     ARI
4/12   NY      TEX
4/13   NAS     WYO
4/13   UTA     DEN
4/13   PHI     MIN
```

I don't even mind if the date column gets sorted differently, I just need the Home and Away columns to reverse their order by Date.  Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

Could also try sorting on row descending:

```
=SORTBY(A2:C7,A2:A7,1,ROW(A2:A7),-1)
```

[image]

```
=VSTACK(A1:C1,SORTBY(A2:C7,A2:A7,1,ROW(A2:A7),-1))
```

(copied from @JvdV) to include headers.

or even

```
=VSTACK(A1:C1,HSTACK(TEXT(A2:A7,"DD-MMM"),SORTBY(B2:C7,A2:A7,1,ROW(A2:A7),-1)))
```

to include the date formatting as well.

Comment: I see I overcomplicated things=)

Comment: It's a great demonstration of the new functions though - I didn't think you should have deleted it.

Comment: I'd like other users to find useful answers more. No worries, yours is the way to go!

Comment: @JvdV Sir, I saw your solution and you have deleted, now how can i see them,

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya after a certain amount of rep on this site you should be able to see deleted answers. Not sure what the boundary is.

Comment: No sir, I don't see any deleted answers here.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to create 3 more columns to do so... The first column created a value for each occurrence of date in the Date column. That looked like this:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)
```

I then dragged the formula throughout the data. So now my table looked like this:

```
Date   Home    Away  Sort
4/12   NY      TEX   1
4/12   TOR     ARI   2
4/12   LA      CIN   3
4/13   PHI     MIN   1
4/13   UTA     DEN   2
4/13   NAS     WYO   3
```

The next column was created to reverse the order of the sort by date:

```
=MAXIFS(D:D,A:A,A2) - D2 + 1
```

Then dragged to the bottom and the new table looked like this:

```
Date   Home    Away  Sort RevSort
4/12   NY      TEX   1    3
4/12   TOR     ARI   2    2
4/12   LA      CIN   3    1
4/13   PHI     MIN   1    3
4/13   UTA     DEN   2    2
4/13   NAS     WYO   3    1
```

My third column Concatenated the Date and RevSort column giving me unique rows which I could then Sort the concatenated column and get my table sorted the way I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by a column other than date if you want the table sorted by something other than date.

If you want it sorted by home team A-Z then sort the home team column A-Z with all other columns selected.

Comment: I don't want it sorted by Home A-Z.  I want it sorted by Date, then I want the Home and Away columns sorted in reverse order of what they are, while still being sorted by Date

Comment: Thats not how sorting works. The two team names are tied to a date, if you sort one column the other 2 will move with them... you cant have separate sorting for separate columns because it changes the data.

Comment: I am fully aware of this.  I figured out what I needed to do.  My answer to my question is posted above.  I probably did a poor job explaining what I was trying to do. My apologies.